# Error in trying to implement csv dataset to r

Tags: r, csv, readr

I am trying to implement a csv dataset to r which is not giving me all the columns in just one column.

Using the code:

```
Education_index <- read_csv("Masteroppgaven/Education index.csv")
```

I have attached a photo of what its giving me.

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

[image: Photo of dataset]

Comment: What if you try with `read_csv2()`?

Comment: Try read_csv(... , delim = “,”)

Comment: read_csv2 did not work, it gave me the same.

Comment: , delim="," gave me an error: Error in read_csv("Masteroppgaven/Education index.csv", delim = ",") : 
  unused argument (delim = ",")